# use a xslt variable to define table padding

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I would like to declare a variable in my xslt file that is styling my xml. I intend to use the variable to pad the tableview cells. depending on what data is being read will depend how far the padding is from the left of the table.

So I was wondering if its possible to then use this padding1 var on tablecell? This is currently how I am attempting this idea, with not much success mind you as when I now load the xml I am getting a blank screen.

Anyway this is my code

```
<xsl:variable name="padding1" select="15"/>

<td style="padding-left: padding1;" colspan="2" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">
```

In the above code I am declaring a variable named padding1 and passing it the value 15, I would then like to use it on padding-left much like you would with a `15px` type value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [AVT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#attribute-value-templates) to reference your variable:

```
<td style="padding-left: {$padding1}px;" colspan="2" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">...</td>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should probably include the unit in your variable. You can even do math operations with the unit intact:

```
<xsl:variable name="content-width">180mm</xsl:variable>
...
<fo:table-column column-width="{$content-width}*0.5"/>
```